# unset an item in an array based on conditional IF statement

Tags: product-attribute, multistore, import, programmatically, ee-1.12.0.2

I have an array that gets imported daily. For the specific field 'special_price' i only want it to import into Main Website > Main Website Store > **Default Store View**

Default store view = 1

```
protected function _getFieldNames()
{
    return array(
        'company_number',
        'sku',
        'style_number',
        'name',
        'div_code',
        'div_desc',
        'color_code',
        'color',
        'size_type',
        'size',
        'price',
        'weight',
        'description',
        'special_price',
        'tax_code',
    );
}
```

I can instantiate the class like so:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

My question is how to parse that one specific field for only the default store and let the other updates run as usual. I assume i'm using an IF statement.

Is it possible to just unset() that item based upon an IF statement?

or... since it's a function would i have to return an array without special price if it met the conditions?

**something like so:**

```
(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() === Mage::app()->getWebsites()[1]->getDefaultStore()->getStoreId()) return array(without special_price);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I noticed this function now that extends the function above:

```
protected function _getFieldNames()
{
    $fieldNames = parent::_getFieldNames();
    $fieldNames[13] = 'specifications';
    $fieldNames[14] = 'frame_color';
    $fieldNames[15] = 'lens_color';
    $fieldNames[43] = 'special_price';

    return $fieldNames;
}
```

I had to add the unique value of 43 which represents the cell from excel when being imported.

---

How about this?

```
protected $_attributesToUpdate = array(
    'name',
    'description',
    'price',
    'tax_class_id',
    'weight',
    'country_of_manufacture',
    'specifications',
    'electric_cn',
    'electric_style',
    'electric_color',
    'electric_div',
    'electric_div_desc',
);
```

Comment: are u make any script for import ?

Comment: @PrashantBarot, yes i have script for import. I'll post it above.

Comment: You can use like this  _getFieldNames($storeid) and in function check if store id is Default store then return different array  as you want.

Comment: My reputation doesn't allow me to comment yet, but do you mean like this?http://pastebin.com/W9tLVmHd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
protected function _getFieldNames()
{
    $arr = array(
        'company_number',
        'sku',
        'style_number',
        'name',
        'div_code',
        'div_desc',
        'color_code',
        'color',
        'size_type',
        'size',
        'price',
        'weight',
        'description',
        'special_price',
        'tax_code',
   );
   if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() === Mage::app()->getWebsites()[1]->getDefaultStore()->getStoreId()) {
       $arr = array_diff($arr, array('special_price'));
   }
   return $arr;
}
```

or like this:

```
protected function _getFieldNames()
{
    $arr = array(
        'company_number',
        'sku',
        'style_number',
        'name',
        'div_code',
        'div_desc',
        'color_code',
        'color',
        'size_type',
        'size',
        'price',
        'weight',
        'description',
   );
   if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() !== Mage::app()->getWebsites()[1]->getDefaultStore()->getStoreId()) {
       $arr[] = 'special_price';
   }
   $arr[] = 'tax_code';
   return $arr;
}
```

for the second method:

```
protected function _getFieldNames()
{
    $fieldNames = parent::_getFieldNames();


    $fieldNames[13] = 'specifications';
    $fieldNames[14] = 'frame_color';
    $fieldNames[15] = 'lens_color';
    $fieldNames[43] = 'special_price';
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() === Mage::app()->getWebsites()[1]->getDefaultStore()->getStoreId()) {
           $fieldNames = array_diff(fieldNames, array('special_price'));
       }

    return $fieldNames;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius, what about the new updated portion of code at the bottom using: $fieldNames = parent::_getFieldNames();

Comment: use the same concept as above to remove the special price from the second one.

Comment: I keep throwing a syntax error because it's not an array?

Comment: The second one just skips special price if it's not equal to the store value and moves on to tax code? I see what you did there... it just appends.

Comment: syntax error @Marius

Comment: figured it out.. getStoreId()))

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error. I didn't test the code.

Comment: No problem.... sorry i feel dumb but how do i add an array like you showed above onto this: protected function _getFieldNames()
{
    $fieldNames = parent::_getFieldNames();

Comment: Any update on the above would be great. Thanks again @Marius

Comment: @Supplement. See my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43491/discussion-between-supplement-and-marius).

Answer (score 0):

If you can do custom coding, there are multiple ways to do this:

- Pass the element which is imported the current store
- Pass website ID to function and then put IF condition.

Comment: Copy the data into another model and then unset the special price data before it gets saved and call save on the copy without the special_price in it? @MageComp

Comment: There is no another model required to save data. I am talking about custom code.